# background-size leaves a one pixel line to the right of my browser

Tags: css, background-size

I'm using:

```
body {
  background:url('../img/wide.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 10%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

However, there's a small `1px` line on the right side of the browser that I can't seem to cover. I tested my site locally on Opera, FF Dev and Chrome - all with the same issue.

Am I missing something?

- Here's what the right side looks like (bad): https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0HAI.png
- Here's what the left side looks like (good): https://i.stack.imgur.com/efYPO.png

Comment: Can you recreate this issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle link if not can you please provide screenshot of your page?

Comment: @dowomenfart, see my edits for a screenshot

Comment: @KshirodraMeher, added screenshots

Comment: just for testing purposes can you add *{padding: 0; margin: 0; line-height: 0;}. I know you're not suppose to do this but I want to check that there isn't any of your styles affecting this.

Comment: @dowomenfart, nothing :(

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this is a browser painting error due to the size of the container falling between pixels. If the container is not set with an exact pixel width, but uses something like percentage, (or if you're zoomed in your browser or using a retina display) then it may be hitting the edge of a pixel and rounding up when drawing the box, and rounding down when drawing the background-image. Might be worth submitting a bug report to the browser vendor.

A workaround solution would be to give an inset box-shadow (as opposed to a regular border). An inset border of 1px will overlap the background image (whereas a border will just make the background image push in 1px from each direction). And since it's a subpixel browser-painting issue, your weird border will never be off by more than 1px.

`box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px gray;`

Not a real solution, but might look better and would blend in with the chrome of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The only bar I see with my solution is the 1px stroke around the browser window, not sure if that's what you're trying to eliminate or not.

```
html{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body{
background: url('http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg') center center no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
padding-top: 10%;
color: #fff;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

[Full Screen Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqoka5L4/2/embedded/result/)

[Code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqoka5L4/2/)

Comment: On OSX, I don't see the 1px stroke from the browser window on the left. Even most websites elements don't produce strokes. Take a look at your Code JSFiddle link. JSFiddle's top blue bar fully extends to both sides of my browser window and I don't see any strokes. This seems to only affect background images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `background-size: 100%;`

```
body {
  background:url('../img/wide.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Also check your image may be your image have a line.

Comment: I gave this a try and still the same issue :(

Comment: please check your image and confirm it has no line

Comment: @Symfony, nope, no bar on my image

Comment: he needs to set margin 0